# Imageview appear black for some images

Tags: android, imageview

When I compile and run the app from android studio, Images work fine on my phone, however when it's installed on other devices through google play, some images appear black.

All photos are supposed to be in drawable folder, and I load them in the recyclerview, here is a the part of code I used to display them on recyclerview adapter :  cl is a constraint Layout

```
    String cardbg = category.category.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","");
    int id = c.getResources().getIdentifier(cardbg, "drawable", c.getPackageName());
    Drawable drawable = c.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    holder.cl.setBackground(drawable);
    //}
```

what could be the reason ?

[image]

Comment: If you want specific help you'll need to provide way more info on what you're doing to display the images, what images they are, where you're getting them from etc. But just in case it helps, low memory can cause parts of the screen to render black, so make sure you're not sticking huge images in there

Comment: Thank you for your inputs , I have modified my question with more details, Would you please take a look

Comment: the code seems fine - how big are the images? width x height? can you debug on one of these other devices? is this code from ``onBindViewHolder``?

Comment: the images are 700x300 all of them , and yes this is from onBindViewHolder.

Comment: If you install the release version on your phone, does it break there too? And are you using ``shrinkResources true`` in your ``build.gradle``? ``getDrawable`` should throw an exception if the drawable doesn't exist though...

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer based on my case.

Make sure that in themes.xml you don't have set up tint to black, as I had below:

```
<resources
   <style name="Theme.AppName parent="xyz"> 
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      <item name="android:tint">@color/black</item> // <-this was wrong for me
   </style>
</resources>
```